# GSM modem library

Tags: c#, .net, sms, serial-port

I'm looking for SMS library that is written in c#, anyone the best library for it and it's free ? I can find more than 1 in Linux, but I'm can't found anything that is written in c# and free

Comment: Its always better to develop the library by own because it makes it easy to build your front end application accordingly.

Comment: Well i can provide the library if reqd.

Answer (score 3):

Most GSM modem will come with a library of it's own. You don't really need the library to be written in C#. Generally it will be in dll or exe. If it's a dll written using C++, you can still call it's function via p/invoke. You just need to know the function signature in order to send and retrieve data from it properly. Check the documentation. If it's an exe, most likely it commandline based, then you can call it by using Process.Start() and putting in what ever you want to send via the argument.

Answer (score 3):

Check out GSMComm.

http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/index.htm